# How can I find the nearest road from my marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have marker (to example lat: 48.363, lng: 17.044) and i need to find road from it in google maps API.

This is my marker:

[image]

I need to change position to this:

[image]

This is just example. I need to change position for every marker which isnt on road in javascript. I searched in google how to find nearby road but i didn't find answer. I can find place from my position but i need the road. Has google maps any method for this??

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696502/google-maps-api-snap-marker-to-nearest-road)?

Comment: it is similar but in directionsService.route i need to wait to return result. This method its async and i need sync method. For some reason i need to add marker outside from directionsService.route.

Comment: You won't find a synchronous method. You might try the [Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro)